# Coffeescript: Why is this function in this class saying its parameter is undefined?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

When I run my code it gives me this error:

> TypeError: pivot is undefined

Here's the relevant class that the error is referring to:

```
class Hero
  constructor: (@color, @direction, @x, @y) ->
  pivots: []
  addPivot: (pivot) -> @pivots.push(pivot)
  onPivot: (pivot) -> pivot.x == @x && pivot.y == @y
  applyPivots: () ->
    indexToRemove = -1
    for i in [0..@pivots.length - 1]
      pivot = @pivots[i]
      if (@onPivot(pivot))
        @direction = pivot.direction
        indexToRemove = i
    @pivots.splice(indexToRemove, 1)
```

Why is this happening? Here's the javascript that it's generating:

```
  Hero = (function() {
    function Hero(color, direction, x, y) {
      this.color = color;
      this.direction = direction;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    Hero.prototype.pivots = [];

    Hero.prototype.addPivot = function(pivot) {
      return this.pivots.push(pivot);
    };

    Hero.prototype.onPivot = function(pivot) {
      return pivot.x === this.x && pivot.y === this.y;
    };

    Hero.prototype.applyPivots = function() {
      var i, indexToRemove, pivot, _i, _ref;

      indexToRemove = -1;
      for (i = _i = 0, _ref = this.pivots.length - 1; 0 <= _ref ? _i <= _ref : _i >= _ref; i = 0 <= _ref ? ++_i : --_i) {
        pivot = this.pivots[i];
        if (this.onPivot(pivot)) {
          this.direction = pivot.direction;
          indexToRemove = i;
        }
      }
      return this.pivots.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    };

    return Hero;

  })();
```

The error is on the line that say:

> ```
>   return pivot.x === this.x && pivot.y === this.y;
> ```

Comment: Just `for pivot, i in @pivots`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with your `for` loop limits. Suppose your `@pivots` array is empty, then the `for` loop in your `applyPivots` will look like this:

```
for i in [0..-1]
  #...
```

so it will start at zero and go down to -1. But `@pivots` is empty so this:

```
pivot = @pivots[i]
```

will give you an `undefined` in `pivot` and everything falls apart in a cascading pile of confusion.

You probably want to use the `for element in array` form of the `for` loop:

```
applyPivots: () ->
  indexToRemove = -1
  for pivot, i in @pivots
    if(@onPivot(pivot))
      @direction = pivot.direction
      indexToRemove = i
  @pivots.splice(indexToRemove, 1) if(indexToRemove >= 0)
```

and presumably you don't want to do anything if nothing is found (i.e. `indexToRemove == -1`) so I threw that in for free.

I think you could go a little further too. Something like this:

```
for pivot, i in @pivots when @onPivot(pivot)
  @direction = pivot.direction
  @pivots.splice(i, 1)
  break
```

You can use `when` to skip over things in a loop that you don't care about and since you only want to remove one thing from `@pivots`, you can break out of the loop as soon as you've found it. This assumes that there will only be on match in `@pivots`, if there can be multiple hits and you really want the last one then you could go backwards by adding `by -1`:

```
for pivot, i in @pivots by -1 when @onPivot(pivot)
  # same as above...
```

You can find more details on `by`, `when`, and other looping goodies in [the fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#loops).

---

While I'm here, don't do this:

```
class Hero
  pivots: []
```

That will attach your array to `Hero`'s prototype so it will be shared by all instances of `Hero`. So if you do this:

```
h1 = new Hero
h2 = new Hero
h1.pivots.push('pancakes')
```

then you'll also see `'pancakes'` in `h2.pivots`. You should give each instance its own array in the constructor:

```
class Hero
  constructor: (@color, @direction, @x, @y) ->
    @pivots = [ ]
```

The same caution applies to any mutable value that you might be tempted to put in the class. Immutable values such as numbers and strings are fine though, you can only assign new values to those and the new value will shadow the prototype's value so no harm will be done.

Comment: Thanks.  It's unfortunate my question is considered too localized, because the information you've provided is extremely useful to understanding coffeescript for many newbies as myself.  In fact, I think what you've written is better than the official manual.

Comment: @tieTYT: You got your answer before the "close everything" crew got their hands on it. Maybe I'll take someone up on their book offers some time :)